# JavaScript 6: testing symbols?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Regarding EcmaScript 6 and symbols: is there any way for us to test their use right now? Some of the nightly versions of the browser already supports them, but unfortunately, their support is limited to @@toStringTag and @@iterator...

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? What's the purpose / use case? You can always do `typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.symbolatoTest`

Comment: I want to test their use. For instance, Symbol.toPrimitive is supposed to be used whenever you need to convert implicitly an object to a primitive type. So, I've created a sample which defines it on an object. Unfortunately, I haven't found a place where I can test my implementation...

Comment: Oh I see. You are using symbols and you simple want to test your code. I don't think there is a general answer to that. You can only really test symbols that are supported by that environment, and even then, the implementation could be faulty or incomplete.

Comment: Thanks Felix. That is what I thought. Using transpilers et al won't help me here...

Comment: Why the close votes ? Question seems clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

The most general solution to use ES6 features before they're available in your engines is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

It can be used both for online testing: https://babeljs.io/repl/

and as a transpiler letting you write ES6 code and deploy as ES5: https://babeljs.io/docs/using-babel/

BUT:

`Symbol.toPrimitive` isn't correctly handled in Babel: [the following code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0Alet%20thing%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5BSymbol.toPrimitive%5D()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%2042%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Aconsole.log(%2Bthing)) logs `NaN` instead of `42`

```
let thing = {
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
        return 42;
    }
};
console.log(+thing)
```

[it's a known caveat](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1364#issuecomment-97428674)

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seems like I'll have to wait a little more before testing my code...

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) that includes polyfills for ECMAScript 5, ECMAScript 6: symbols, collections, iterators, promises, ECMAScript 7 proposals; setImmediate, and array generics.